# How to expose error during Kentico development

Tags: c#, error-handling, kentico

I miss the yellow screen of death when I do development in Kentico. Every time an error happens it just shows 502 bad gateway, even if I have custom error turned off in web.config. To make it even worse, there is nothing regarding the error in the event log.

So how can I get the original c# .Net error back when I develop in Kentico?

Answer (score 2):

If your project builds properly in Visual Studio, you have no events in the Kentico Event log, you have debugging enabled in the web.config AND you have the web.config key to display errors on the page, then check the IIS Event logs, they should have some more info for you.

```
<add key="CMSDisplayApplicationErrorMessages" value="true" />
```